# Php add html after successful upload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this script for uploading files.  I want to display a certain HTML message/div if the file upload was successful. How can I add it to the script?

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#uploadForm').submit(function(e) { 
  if($('#userImage').val()) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
    target:   '#targetLayer', 
    beforeSubmit: function() {
      $("#progress-bar").width('0%');
    },
    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete){ 
     $("#progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
     $("#progress-bar").html('<div id="progress-status">' + percentComplete +' %</div>')
    },
    success:function (){

    },
    resetForm: true 
   }); 
   // return false; 
  }
 });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: by adding the html in the success-function()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this under success

```
success:function (){

            $("#progress-bar").html("Successfully completed")
},
```